# How to distribute ranking using MySQL Query and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have to distribute ranking to the 5000 students in an exam. Ranking is based on the score and the time taken (in seconds) to obtain that score.

For example is 5 students have same score, then taken will be the criteria to calculate their ranks otherwise score should be the criteria to calculate their ranks.

Following is my table `tbRank`

```
ID  StudID  Score Time Date        Rank
1   11      8     60   09-11-2013 
2   22      6     45   09-11-2013
3   33      4     76   09-11-2013
4   44      6     67   09-11-2013
5   55      8     35   09-11-2013 
6   66      8     35   08-11-2013
7   77      8     39   08-11-2013
```

Now `rank column` in above table should be updated as:

```
ID  StudID  Score Time Date        Rank
1   11      8     60   09-11-2013  2
2   22      6     45   09-11-2013  3
3   33      4     76   09-11-2013  5
4   44      6     67   09-11-2013  4
5   55      8     35   09-11-2013  1
6   66      8     35   08-11-2013  1
7   77      8     39   08-11-2013  2
```

I want to make a MySQL Query to do this business. Similarly there can be more than 10000 records in the table. So I need an optimized query for this functionality.

Note: I am using PHP and MYSQL.

`Update:` Everyday almost 5000 new entries will be created in the table and after all insertions are made, rank column will be updated once in a day. Now please suggest me the best way to do this. If I update rank column in the table, then only once I will have to do it, otherwise everytime while fetching the rank of the student, I will have to make calculations.

Comment: Hmm,, I'm sorry about that. i have try it in my mysql. So I have the solution.

Comment: you had included php here , so question is the rank column will be an additional column in your table or just a display in php?

Comment: @DrixsonOseña - To be very honest, I don't know how should I do it? Whether I keep a column in the table or just calculate it runtime to show on the wep page? I need suggestions.

Comment: @nkp  As i mentioned in my answer, the disadvantage of having a column with the rank is that whenever you enter a new record or modify an existing one, you would have to do the update again, because you would have to recalculate to make the table accurate. If you remove that column and do only the rank from my second query, you don't have to worry about the table and whenever you need to get the rank, you just do the select for it.

Comment: @FilipeSilva - I am satisfied with your second query. But in my requirement, table will be updated only once in a day. I forgot to mention date field in my table. I the query I have to consider date also i,e do update rank where date is of today. I am updating my question.

Comment: @nkp. I updated my answer to handle only today's records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update the table you can do:

```sql
UPDATE tbRank t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ID, StudID, Score, `Time`, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM (
    SELECT ID, StudID, Score, `Time`
    FROM tbRank
    WHERE date = date(now())
    ORDER BY score DESC, `time` ASC
    ) a
  JOIN (
    SELECT @rownum := 0
    ) r
  ) b ON b.id = t.id
SET t.rank = b.rank
```

But since you would do this every day, you would have to update all rows of rank column to null before executing this.

I wouldn't advise this approach because if you change one of them or insert a new record, you have to do the update again.

You can simply use this query whenever you want to get the ranking:

```sql
SELECT ID, StudID, Score, `Time`, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM (
    SELECT ID, StudID, Score, `Time`
    FROM tbRank
    WHERE date = date(now())
    ORDER BY score DESC, `time` ASC
    ) a
  JOIN (
    SELECT @rownum := 0
    ) r
```

Additionally, if you want to know the rank of a specific student, you can do the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT ID, StudID, Score, `Time`, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM (
    SELECT ID, StudID, Score, `Time`
    FROM tbRank
    WHERE date = date(now())
    ORDER BY score DESC, `time` ASC
    ) a
  JOIN (
    SELECT @rownum := 0
    ) r
  ) b
WHERE b.StudID = 11;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3ac2/2)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

So, this is your table :

```
ID  StudID  Score Time
1   11      8     60 
2   22      6     45 
3   33      4     76
4   44      6     67
5   55      8     35
```

This is the query to build the `Rank`:

```
SELECT * FROM tbRank GROUP BY Score DESC, Time ASC
```

It will 'rearrange' the row of your table with the highest score and fastest time will be arranged from top to bottom

Comment: This will sort my table as desired by me. What about ranking column? I have to give rank to each and every student.

Comment: If you want that, `Rank` column must be an `alias`. See @Filipe Silva's answer. I think that's a right solution for you